# onScrollEnd event not firing when using iscrollview

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iscroll4, iscrollview

I am using jquery mobile and iscroll/iscrollview on a page that contains a listview so that the listview contents are scrolled.  The listview is scrolling just fine.  **The problem is** that the listview items are accidentally getting clicked when the list is scrolled.

If you have any solutions let me know.

I have been, unsuccessfully, trying to bind to the onScrollEnd event so that I can set a variable (scroll_stop_time) to the time that the scrolling stopped.

I also have a pagebeforechange event that is checking the time value of the scroll_stop_time variable and if the time is too recent (less than 200ms ago) then I stop the click.

However, I can't get the onscrollend event to fire so the scroll_stop_time is never updated and all clicks are getting through.

**My Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/resources/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/resources/css/jqm-icon-pack-2.0-original.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/resources/js/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/resources/css/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/resources/css/fileuploader.css" type="text/css" media="all" />



    <script src="mobile/resources/js/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jquery.postjson.js"></script>

    <script>
      var scroll_stop_time = (new Date).getTime(); // initialize the variable

      $(document).on("iscroll_init", function() {
        console.log('iscroll INIT');
        $.mobile.iscrollview.prototype.options.onScrollEnd = function(){
            console.log('--iscroll onScrollEnd');
            scroll_stop_time=(new Date).getTime(); // update the variable with the current time         
        };
      });
    </script>


    <script src="mobile/resources/js/iscroll4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jstorage.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jquery.validate-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mobile/resources/js/fileuploader.js"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log('head javascript - before JQM is loaded');


        // ==============================================
        // ALL PAGES - EVERY TIME THEY ARE DISPLAYED
        // ==============================================
            // -- all pages - pagebeforechange event --
            $(document).on( "pagebeforechange", function( event, data ){
                if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {
                    console.log('all pages - pagebeforechange event - (every time ANY page is about to be displayed)');
                    console.log(data);
                    // intercept a page change request
                    // can alter any aspect of this request, if needed

                    if(data.toPage.indexOf("manage-inventory") != -1){
                        // make sure we haven't just recently stopped an iScroll scroller (not really a clicked link)
                        elapsed_time = ((new Date).getTime()) - scroll_stop_time;
                        console.log('scroller has been stopped for '+ elapsed_time);
                        if(elapsed_time  < 200){
                            // user just stopped the scroller and really didnt mean to click on the listview item link
                            console.log('not really a click'); 
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
    </script>


    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="page_manage-inventory-items_by_type" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">

<div data-role="header">
            <a href="#panel_nav_manage-inventory-items_by_type" data-icon="direction" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-role="button"></a>
                <a href="#panel_settings_manage-inventory-items_by_type" data-icon="menu" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right"></a>
            <h1>Items by Type</h1>
</div>


<div data-role="content">


<style type="text/css" media="all">

.listview-wrapper, .listview-wrapper div.iscroll-scroller {
    width: 100% !important;
}

</style>



<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
    <label for="iibt_search">Item Search:</label>
    <input type="search" class="item_search" name="iibt_search" id="iibt_search" value="" />
</div>




    <h2>Items by Type:</h2>

<style type="text/css">


</style>


<div class="listview-wrapper" data-iscroll>

<ul id="iibt_listview" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
            <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=1&specific_name=Blu-Ray Players&specific_class=t">Blu-Ray Players<span class="ui-li-count">187</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=2&specific_name=CD-ROM Players&specific_class=t">CD-ROM Players<span class="ui-li-count">416</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=3&specific_name=Computers&specific_class=t">Computers<span class="ui-li-count">104</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=4&specific_name=Data Panels&specific_class=t">Data Panels<span class="ui-li-count">253</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=5&specific_name=Data Projectors&specific_class=t">Data Projectors<span class="ui-li-count">160</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=6&specific_name=Digital Cameras&specific_class=t">Digital Cameras<span class="ui-li-count">424</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=7&specific_name=DVD Players&specific_class=t">DVD Players<span class="ui-li-count">347</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=8&specific_name=Easels&specific_class=t">Easels<span class="ui-li-count">372</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=9&specific_name=Flipcharts&specific_class=t">Flipcharts<span class="ui-li-count">441</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=10&specific_name=Laptops&specific_class=t">Laptops<span class="ui-li-count">125</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=11&specific_name=MAC Monitor Cables&specific_class=t">MAC Monitor Cables<span class="ui-li-count">166</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=18&specific_name=Monitors&specific_class=t">Monitors<span class="ui-li-count">315</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=12&specific_name=Overheads&specific_class=t">Overheads<span class="ui-li-count">255</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=13&specific_name=Podiums&specific_class=t">Podiums<span class="ui-li-count">500</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=14&specific_name=Power Supplies&specific_class=t">Power Supplies<span class="ui-li-count">174</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=15&specific_name=Screens&specific_class=t">Screens<span class="ui-li-count">398</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=16&specific_name=Stereos&specific_class=t">Stereos<span class="ui-li-count">469</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=17&specific_name=TVs&specific_class=t">TVs<span class="ui-li-count">101</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=19&specific_name=VGV/MCGA Cables&specific_class=t">VGV/MCGA Cables<span class="ui-li-count">111</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=20&specific_name=Video Cameras&specific_class=t">Video Cameras<span class="ui-li-count">470</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=21&specific_name=Video Projectors&specific_class=t">Video Projectors<span class="ui-li-count">495</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=22&specific_name=Visualizers&specific_class=t">Visualizers<span class="ui-li-count">470</span></a>
            </li>
            </ul>

</div>


</div>


        <div id="fixed_footer" data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="text-align: center;">
        <div style="display:inline-block; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">manage-inventory-items_by_type</div>
        </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

**I get the following output in the browser console:**

```
    head javascript - before JQM is loaded  
    mobileinit  
    iscroll INIT    
    {Note:  I scroll around now until I accidentally click a listview link}
    {this is where the onScrollEnd console log info would show up if I were capturing it}
    all pages - pageshow event - (every time ANY page is displayed)
    scroller has been stopped for 28995
    {ajax post info,  other page is loaded, etc..}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that some of the examples included in the iscrollview download package are binding to some of the iscroll events.  Using those examples as a guide, I came up with the following working solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/resources/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/resources/css/jqm-icon-pack-2.0-original.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/resources/js/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/resources/css/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/resources/css/fileuploader.css" type="text/css" media="all" />



    <script src="mobile/resources/js/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jquery.postjson.js"></script>      
    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jstorage.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jquery.validate-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mobile/resources/js/fileuploader.js"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log('head javascript - before JQM is loaded');

        var scroll_stop_time = (new Date).getTime(); // initialize the variable
        var is_scrolling = false;           


        // ==============================================
        // ALL PAGES - EVERY TIME THEY ARE DISPLAYED
        // ==============================================
            // -- all pages - pagebeforechange event --
            $(document).on( "pagebeforechange", function( event, data ){
                if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {
                    console.log('all pages - pagebeforechange event - (every time ANY page is about to be displayed)');
                    console.log(data);
                    // intercept a page change request
                    // can alter any aspect of this request, if needed

                    if(data.toPage.indexOf("manage-inventory") != -1){
                        // make sure we haven't just recently stopped an iScroll scroller (not really a clicked link)
                        elapsed_time = ((new Date).getTime()) - scroll_stop_time;                           
                        if(elapsed_time  < 200 || is_scrolling){
                            //console.log('not really a click');
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        // ==============================================
        // SPECIFIC PAGES - ON INITIAL LOAD ONLY
        // ==============================================               

        $(document).on("pageinit", "#page_manage-inventory-items_by_type2", function() {
            console.log('#page_manage-inventory-items_by_type2 - pageinit event -- (only once for THIS page)');

            $(".iscroll-wrapper", this).bind( {
                //iscroll_onscrollstart : function(){
                //  console.log('ON SCROLL START');
                //  is_scrolling=true;
                    // didn't work here because even a static click would
                    // fire this event but the onscrollend would never fire
                    // because it really wasn't scrolling
                //},
                iscroll_onscrollmove : function(){
                    //console.log('ON SCROLL MOVE');
                    is_scrolling=true;
                },
                iscroll_onscrollend : function(){
                    //console.log('ON SCROLL END');
                    is_scrolling=false;
                    scroll_stop_time=(new Date).getTime();
                }

            });

        });

    </script>


    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile/resources/js/iscroll4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js"></script>
    <script src="mobile/resources/js/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="page_manage-inventory-items_by_type" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">

<div data-role="header">
            <a href="#panel_nav_manage-inventory-items_by_type" data-icon="direction" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-role="button"></a>
                <a href="#panel_settings_manage-inventory-items_by_type" data-icon="menu" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right"></a>
            <h1>Items by Type</h1>
</div>


<div data-role="content">


<style type="text/css" media="all">

.listview-wrapper, .listview-wrapper div.iscroll-scroller {
    width: 100% !important;
}

</style>



<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
    <label for="iibt_search">Item Search:</label>
    <input type="search" class="item_search" name="iibt_search" id="iibt_search" value="" />
</div>




    <h2>Items by Type:</h2>

<style type="text/css">


</style>


<div class="listview-wrapper" data-iscroll>

<ul id="iibt_listview" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
            <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=1&specific_name=Blu-Ray Players&specific_class=t">Blu-Ray Players<span class="ui-li-count">187</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=2&specific_name=CD-ROM Players&specific_class=t">CD-ROM Players<span class="ui-li-count">416</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=3&specific_name=Computers&specific_class=t">Computers<span class="ui-li-count">104</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=4&specific_name=Data Panels&specific_class=t">Data Panels<span class="ui-li-count">253</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=5&specific_name=Data Projectors&specific_class=t">Data Projectors<span class="ui-li-count">160</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=6&specific_name=Digital Cameras&specific_class=t">Digital Cameras<span class="ui-li-count">424</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=7&specific_name=DVD Players&specific_class=t">DVD Players<span class="ui-li-count">347</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=8&specific_name=Easels&specific_class=t">Easels<span class="ui-li-count">372</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=9&specific_name=Flipcharts&specific_class=t">Flipcharts<span class="ui-li-count">441</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=10&specific_name=Laptops&specific_class=t">Laptops<span class="ui-li-count">125</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=11&specific_name=MAC Monitor Cables&specific_class=t">MAC Monitor Cables<span class="ui-li-count">166</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=18&specific_name=Monitors&specific_class=t">Monitors<span class="ui-li-count">315</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=12&specific_name=Overheads&specific_class=t">Overheads<span class="ui-li-count">255</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=13&specific_name=Podiums&specific_class=t">Podiums<span class="ui-li-count">500</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=14&specific_name=Power Supplies&specific_class=t">Power Supplies<span class="ui-li-count">174</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=15&specific_name=Screens&specific_class=t">Screens<span class="ui-li-count">398</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=16&specific_name=Stereos&specific_class=t">Stereos<span class="ui-li-count">469</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=17&specific_name=TVs&specific_class=t">TVs<span class="ui-li-count">101</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=19&specific_name=VGV/MCGA Cables&specific_class=t">VGV/MCGA Cables<span class="ui-li-count">111</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=20&specific_name=Video Cameras&specific_class=t">Video Cameras<span class="ui-li-count">470</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=21&specific_name=Video Projectors&specific_class=t">Video Projectors<span class="ui-li-count">495</span></a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="manage-inventory-items_by_specific.php?specific_id=22&specific_name=Visualizers&specific_class=t">Visualizers<span class="ui-li-count">470</span></a>
            </li>
            </ul>

</div>


</div>


        <div id="fixed_footer" data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="text-align: center;">
        <div style="display:inline-block; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">manage-inventory-items_by_type</div>
        </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a good demmo for you.
take care about link .
http://davidwalsh.name/iphone-scrollbars

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <title>example up and load</title>
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
        $("#list").bind('pageinit', function () {   
            $.ajax({
                 type: "get",
                 async: false,
                 url: "http://www.57lehuo.com/index.php?a=index&m=api&method=itemsSearchGet&keyword=连衣裙&sign=5cb85c3eed22c1908e05c584813c8dd2",
                 dataType: "jsonp",
                 jsonp: "callback",
                 jsonpCallback:"itemsSearchGet",
                 success: function(json){   
                     var content='';
                      $.each( json['result'], function(i, n){                       
                        var url=n.url!='undefined'?n.url:'';
                        var bimg=n.bimg!='undefined'?n.bimg:'';
                        var title=n.title!='undefined'?n.title:'';
                        content = content + "<li>";
                        content = content + "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://s.click.taobao.com/t?e=zGU34CA7K%2BPkqB05%2Bm7rfGGjlY60oHcc7bkKOQiRddrNEyGLx31dnc6%2Fz%2BaQS2UNDUWpebTcEEjBuk1W5odmLS8%3D&pid=mm_30949159_0_0\">";
                        content = content + "<img src=\""+bimg+"_100x100.jpg\" />";
                        content = content + "<h2>";
                        content = content + "clothes";
                        content = content + "</h2>";
                        content = content + "<p>";
                        content = content + title;
                        content = content + "</p>";             
                        content = content + "</a>";
                        content = content + "</li>";
                    });             
                    $("#thelist").append(content).listview('refresh');      

                 },
                 error: function(){
                     //alert('fail');
                 }
             });        

        });
        $("#list").bind("pagebeforeshow", function(){       
            setTimeout(loaded, 10); 
        });

    })

    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    var myScroll,
        pullDownEl, pullDownOffset,
        pullUpEl, pullUpOffset,
        generatedCount = 0;

    /**
     * down update 
     * myScroll.refresh();      
     */
    var p=2;
    function pullDownAction () {

            $.ajax({
                 type: "get",
                 async: false,
                 url: "http://www.57lehuo.com/index.php?a=index&m=api&method=itemsSearchGet&keyword=连衣裙&p="+p+"",
                 dataType: "jsonp",
                 jsonp: "callback",
                 jsonpCallback:"itemsSearchGet",
                 success: function(json){   
                     var content='';
                      $.each( json['result'], function(i, n){                       
                        var url=n.url!='undefined'?n.url:'';
                        var bimg=n.bimg!='undefined'?n.bimg:'';
                        var title=n.title!='undefined'?n.title:'';
                        content = content + "<li>";
                        content = content + "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://s.click.taobao.com/t?e=zGU34CA7K%2BPkqB05%2Bm7rfGGjlY60oHcc7bkKOQiRddrNEyGLx31dnc6%2Fz%2BaQS2UNDUWpebTcEEjBuk1W5odmLS8%3D&pid=mm_30949159_0_0\">";
                        content = content + "<img src=\""+bimg+"_100x100.jpg\" />";
                        content = content + "<h2>";
                        content = content + "clothes";
                        content = content + "</h2>";
                        content = content + "<p>";
                        content = content + title;
                        content = content + "</p>";             
                        content = content + "</a>";
                        content = content + "</li>";
                    });             
                    $("#thelist").prepend(content).listview('refresh');

                 },
                 error: function(){
                    // alert('fail');
                 }
             });        
            p++;    

            myScroll.refresh();     //update new page       Remember to 
    }

    /**
     *  do itself
     * myScroll.refresh();      // update new page
     */
    function pullUpAction () {
        setTimeout(function () {    // <-- Simulate network congestion, remove setTimeout from production!
            /*      
            var el, li, i;
            el = document.getElementById('thelist');

            for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
                li = document.createElement('li');
                li.innerText = 'Generated row ' + (++generatedCount);
                el.appendChild(li, el.childNodes[0]);
            }
            */

            var content = "";
            for (var i=1;i<3;i++){
                content = content + "<li>";
                content = content + "<a href=\"#\">";
                content = content + "<img src=\"images/album-bb.jpg\" />";
                content = content + "<h2>";
                content = content + "add new content<br/>"+new Date();
                content = content + "</h2>";
                content = content + "<p>";
                content = content + "Broken Bells";
                content = content + "</p>";             
                content = content + "</a>";
                content = content + "</li>";
            }
            $("#thelist").append(content).listview('refresh');

            myScroll.refresh();     // update new page       Remember to  Remember to refresh when contents are loaded (ie: on ajax completion)
        }, 1000);   // <-- Simulate network congestion, remove setTimeout from production!
    }

    /**
     * began iScroll
     */
    function loaded() {

        if(myScroll!=null){
            myScroll.destroy();
        }

        pullDownEl = document.getElementById('pullDown');
        pullDownOffset = pullDownEl.offsetHeight;
        pullUpEl = document.getElementById('pullUp');   
        pullUpOffset = pullUpEl.offsetHeight;

        myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
            useTransition: true,    //default true
            //useTransition: false, 
            topOffset: pullDownOffset,
            onRefresh: function () {
                if (pullDownEl.className.match('loading')) {
                    pullDownEl.className = '';
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'down update...';
                } else if (pullUpEl.className.match('loading')) {
                    pullUpEl.className = '';
                    pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'up update...';
                }
            },
            onScrollMove: function () {
                if (this.y > 5 && !pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullDownEl.className = 'flip';
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'down update...';
                    this.minScrollY = 0;
                } else if (this.y < 5 && pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullDownEl.className = '';
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'down update...';
                    this.minScrollY = -pullDownOffset;
                } else if (this.y < (this.maxScrollY - 5) && !pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullUpEl.className = 'flip';
                    pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'update...';
                    this.maxScrollY = this.maxScrollY;
                } else if (this.y > (this.maxScrollY + 5) && pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullUpEl.className = '';
                    pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'up date...';
                    this.maxScrollY = pullUpOffset;
                }
            },
            onScrollEnd: function () {
                if (pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullDownEl.className = 'loading';
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'loading...';                
                    pullDownAction();   // Execute custom function (ajax call?)
                } else if (pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullUpEl.className = 'loading';
                    pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'loading...';                
                    pullUpAction(); // Execute custom function (ajax call?)
                }
            }
        });

        setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById('wrapper').style.left = '0'; }, 800);
    }


    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

    //document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200); }, false);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false); 
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iscroll.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="list"> 
    <div id="header"><a href="#">product list</a></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="scroller">
            <div id="pullDown">
                <span class="pullDownIcon"></span><span class="pullDownLabel">Pull down to refresh...</span>
            </div>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false" id="thelist">            
                <li><a href="#">
                    <img src="images/album-p.jpg">
                    <h3> Amadeus Phoenix</h3>
                    <p>Phoenix</p></a>
                </li>
            </ul>       
            <div id="pullUp">
                <span class="pullUpIcon"></span><span class="pullUpLabel">Pull up to refresh...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="a">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-active" data-ajax="false">index</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```